# Superset import-dashboard cli overwrite existing slices

Tags: import, dashboard, apache-superset

If the dashboard json was exported from different instances of superset.

On import, it will import dashboard as what the slice as hardcoded in the json.  |
For example:
dashboard 1 has 10 slices (slice id 1 - 10)
dashboard 2 has 5 slices (slice id 1 - 5)

After import dashboard 1 and then import dashboard 2. The slice 1-5 of dashboard 1 will break because it was replaced by the metadata inside of the slice 1-5 of dashboard 2.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: I see a ticket for this that unfortunately is marked as closed due to non-activity
https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/4070
This is caused by integer IDs causing existing widgets be overwritten.